# Is it safe to connect two VGA output ports together?

Tags: graphics-card, vga

I have two desktop machines that I intend to control using Intel vPro with its out-of-band management. It appears that graphics are not rendered unless a display is connected, so I will not be able to get video output if I just run them headless. I have plugged both ends of one VGA cable into both of the VGA ports, and this is sufficient to trick the machine into rendering graphics.

Is there any danger the hardware with this setup?

Comment: This shouldn't cause any issues, or at least none that i can think of.

Comment: Good question. +1 for sparking my interest. I know voltage goes over these cables, and in essense you're causing a short circuit this way. But if this was to prone to problems, they would not have made both sides female and the cable both males. I honestly don't know, but it is something I would not use myself unless someone can prove that this is not dangarous to do.

Comment: The 'right' way to do this is to get/build a dummy VGA plug. kinda wierd that it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [VGA pinout](http://pinouts.ru/Video/VGAVesaDdc_pinout.shtml) pin 9 sends +5V from the computer to the monitor. If you connect two computers together, they'll be sending +5V at each other. While this might not be enough to immediately damage the hardware, it's not something I would do long term.

You can get a [VGA dummy plug](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EAY13GC) for under $20, it's not worth risking your hardware when an electrically safe alternative is available.

If you can make custom cables, you can [make your own VGA dummy plug.](http://www.geeks3d.com/20091230/vga-hack-how-to-make-a-vga-dummy-plug/)

VGA dummy plug is probably not the correct term for this, but it's what brings in the results on Google.